# Add values from one collection to another in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: plsql, oracle19c

I have a collection which is of type Table of varchar2
let's call it col1

it can hold values like

```
aaa
bbb,ccc
ddd,eee;fff
ggg|hhh
```

I need to add all values as single values to another collection col2
there are delimiters like ,;|

so the new col2 will hold

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
ggg
hhh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE string_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
```

Then you can create the function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  CLOB,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN string_list DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_list         string_list := string_list();
  p_items        PLS_INTEGER;
  c_pattern      CONSTANT VARCHAR2(4000) := '(.*?)(' || i_delim || '|$)';
BEGIN
  IF LENGTH(i_str) > 0 THEN
    p_items := REGEXP_COUNT( i_str, c_pattern ) - 1;
    p_list.EXTEND(p_items);
    FOR i IN 1 .. p_items LOOP
      p_list(i) := REGEXP_SUBSTR(i_str, c_pattern, 1, i, NULL, 1);
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_list;
END;
/
```

Then you can do it all in PL/SQL (without context-switching back and forth from PL/SQL to SQL):

```sql
DECLARE
  col1 string_list := string_list('aaa', 'bbb,ccc', 'ddd,eee;fff', 'ggg|hhh');
  col2 string_list := string_list();
BEGIN
  col2 := split_string(col1(1), '[^a-z]');
  FOR i IN 2 .. col1.COUNT LOOP
    col2 := col2 MULTISET UNION ALL split_string(col1(i), '[^a-z]');
  END LOOP;

  FOR i IN 1 .. col2.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(col2(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
ggg
hhh
```

---

If you want to merge the function into the PL/SQL block then:

```sql
DECLARE
  col1    string_list := string_list('aaa', 'bbb,ccc', 'ddd,eee;fff', 'ggg|hhh');
  col2    string_list := string_list();
  items   PLS_INTEGER;
  pattern CONSTANT VARCHAR2(4000) := '(.*?)([^a-z]|$)';
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. col1.COUNT LOOP
    items := REGEXP_COUNT( col1(i), pattern ) - 1;
    col2.EXTEND(items);
    FOR j IN 1 .. items LOOP
      col2(col2.COUNT - items + j) := REGEXP_SUBSTR(
        col1(i), pattern, 1, j, NULL, 1
      );
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;

  FOR i IN 1 .. col2.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(col2(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which outputs the same as previously.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NL4AwvHH)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the coolest code but this works:

```
set serveroutput on size 999999
clear screen
DECLARE
   TYPE t_tab IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(128);
   l_tab1 t_tab := t_tab(
   'aaa'
   ,'bbb,ccc'
   ,'ddd,eee;fff'
   ,'ggg|hhh'
   );
   l_tab2 t_tab := t_tab();
   l_temp VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN l_tab1.FIRST .. l_tab1.LAST LOOP
    --replace separators with comma
    l_temp := REPLACE(l_tab1(i),';',',');
    l_temp := REPLACE(l_temp,'|',',');
    --split by comm
    FOR j IN 
    (SELECT
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(l_temp, '[^,]+', 1, level) AS parts
         FROM dual
         CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(l_temp, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
    )
    LOOP
      l_tab2.extend;
      l_tab2(l_tab2.LAST) := j.parts;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
  FOR r IN l_tab2.FIRST .. l_tab2.LAST LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('New: '|| l_tab2(r)); 
  END LOOP;
END;
/

New: aaa
New: bbb
New: ccc
New: ddd
New: eee
New: fff
New: ggg
New: hhh
```

If you have Oracle APEX installed, then you could take advantage of the `apex_string` api:

```
set serveroutput on size 999999
clear screen
DECLARE
   l_tab1 apex_t_varchar2 := apex_t_varchar2(
      'aaa'
      ,'bbb,ccc'
      ,'ddd,eee;fff'
      ,'ggg|hhh'
   );
   l_tab2 apex_t_varchar2 := apex_t_varchar2();
   l_tab_tmp apex_t_varchar2;

   l_temp VARCHAR2(4000); 
   
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. l_tab1.COUNT LOOP
    --replace separators with comma
    l_temp := REPLACE(l_tab1(i),';',',');
    l_temp := REPLACE(l_temp,'|',',');
    l_tab_tmp := apex_string.split(l_temp,',');
    l_tab2 := l_tab2 MULTISET UNION l_tab_tmp;
  END LOOP;
  FOR r IN l_tab2.FIRST .. l_tab2.LAST LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(apex_string.format('New: %0', l_tab2(r)));  
  END LOOP;  
END;
/

New: aaa
New: bbb
New: ccc
New: ddd
New: eee
New: fff
New: ggg
New: hhh
```